# Display data from class subcategory in tableview Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, pointers, parse-platform

I have two classes in the Parse backend. 
Classes: 
- Category->Kategorien (image, name)
- Subcategory->Unterkategorien (image, name, category(pointer))

I want a TableView for each class. It should be like, I choose a Category in the first TableView and come to the next TableView with all Subcategories of the chosen Category.

With the following code I show the data from the Category class:

```
import UIKit

class KategorienTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Kategorien"
    self.textKey = "name"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Kategorien")
    query.orderByAscending("name")
    return query
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("KategorienTableCell") as KategorienTableCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = KategorienTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "KategorienTableCell")
    }

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    cell.name.text = object["name"] as String!

    var thumbnail = object["bild"] as PFFile
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "Kategorien")
    cell.bild.image = initialThumbnail
    cell.bild.file = thumbnail
    cell.bild.loadInBackground()

    return cell
}

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var unterkategorienScene = segue.destinationViewController as UnterkategorienTableViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the unterkategorien view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        unterkategorienScene.aktuellesObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        //println(unterkategorienScene.aktuellesObject)
    }
}
}
```

Now I have the problem that I don't know how to display all subcategories (unterkategorien) of the chosen Category in the second TableViewController. The Subcategories have a Parse pointer to the Categories but how should I use that in this case?
At the moment it displays all Subcategories in the second Tableview when I first choose a Category in the first TableView.

My code of the second TableViewController actually looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class UnterkategorienTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
var aktuellesObject : PFObject?



  // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Unterkategorien"

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {


    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UnterkategorienTableCell") as UnterkategorienTableCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UnterkategorienTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "UnterkategorienTableCell")
    }

    if let objecti = aktuellesObject?{

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        cell.unterkategorienName.text = object["name"] as String!
        //println(object["name"].objectId)

        var thumbnail = object["bild"] as PFFile
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "Kategorien")
        cell.unterkategorienBild.image = initialThumbnail
        cell.unterkategorienBild.file = thumbnail
        cell.unterkategorienBild.loadInBackground()
    }

    return cell
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create the void which you created in the main (KategorienTableViewController) called `queryForTable()`?
But then you need the current category which you have to pass via the prepareForSegue (what you already did) but you need to pass the Category and not the subcategory.

It would look something like this:

KategorienTableViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var unterkategorienScene = segue.destinationViewController as UnterkategorienTableViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the unterkategorien view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        unterkategorienScene.aktuellesObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        //println(unterkategorienScene.aktuellesObject)
    }
}
```

UnterkategorienTableViewController:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName)
    query.whereKey("category", equalTo: aktuellesObject)
    return query
}
```

ps. Wie ich sehe sprichst du Deutsch, probier nicht Deutsch und Englisch während dem Programmieren zu vermischen das sorgt für Chaos.

Comment: Thanks that's it. 
PS: Vielen Dank für den Tipp.